# Is there a way to specify a region of an image using python pytesseract module along with Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract

I have a paper with boxes that contain fields in which I want to extract data from.  Currently I am using the quickstart found here https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

In particular, I use the image_to_boxes to extract the data, however the program reads lines top to bottom and left to right and not boxes themselves top to bottom left to right.  So I was wondering if I could parse the data within the boxes themselves of a certain region of my data sheet.

The results read 'Part Operation:150 Number: RG45X12-G'
instead of 'Part Number: RG45X12-G Operation: 150'

Comment: If it is not too late, can you share a sample with us?